# how to match un-linked vertexes in Gremlin in connected graph

Tags: graph, gremlin

I have a simple graph, with people nodes (let's say over 10K people nodes) and rules nodes (about a handful of rules) that are NOT already linked, no edges exist between these two type of nodes. What i want to do is to create edges between them by matching properties value in Gremlin.

people nodes has four properties: name, age, state, registered.
rule nodes has three property: age, state, registered.. different rule nodes would have different property value such as (registered=true, state=WA, age > 22) etc.

How do I write a gremlin that can link all the people nodes that have matching properties value with each of the rule nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample graph, given the additional information in the comments, could look like this:

```
g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
g.addV('person').
    property('name','daniel').
    property('age',37).
    property('state','AZ').
  addV('person').
    property('name','howell').
    property('age',25).
    property('state','WA').
  addV('person').
    property('name','john').
    property('age',19).
    property('state','NV').
  addV('rule').
    property('state','WA').
    property('state','CA').
    property('state','OR').
    property('minimumAge',22).
  addV('rule').
    property('state','AZ').
    property('state','FL').
    property('state','TX').
    property('minimumAge',19).
  iterate()
```

I'm not quite sure if the `age > 22` was intentional, but let's assume that you're actually only looking for equality matches; then your query would be:

```
g.V().hasLabel('people').as('person').
  V().hasLabel('rule').
    where(eq('person')).
      by(values('age','state','registered').fold()).
  addE('hasRule').
    from('person')
```

To match the `person` and `rule` vertices, you would do something similar to this (adding more rules as you need them):

```
g.V().hasLabel('person').as('person').
  V().hasLabel('rule').
    where(lte('person')).by('minimumAge').by('age').
    filter(values('state').where(eq('person')).by().by('state')).
  addE('hasRule').
    from('person').iterate()
```

This query would add 2 edges in the sample graph (there's no rule for `john` as he's just too young):

```
gremlin> g.V().outE().inV().path().by('name').by(label).by(valueMap())
==>[daniel,hasRule,[minimumAge:[19],state:[AZ,FL,TX]]]
==>[howell,hasRule,[minimumAge:[22],state:[WA,CA,OR]]]
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the matching conditions would need to be beyond simple equalities like greater than and less than. for example, some people nodes can only be linked to rule nodes that specifies age < 22.  These rules nodes would further linked out to product nodes such as alcohol or cigarettes. so the end objective is to find the products suitable for people matching certain rule conditions.

Comment: But how do the rule properties look like? Is it like a String `'< 22'` or two separate properties, like `predicate=lt` and `age=22`?

Comment: ah, good quesiton.  for age property on rule, it's actually called minimumAge, so any people's age needs to be bigger than this value when specified. For state property, it's usually a multi cardinality list like ["WA", "CA", "OR], so only people like in these states can fit the rules.

Comment: Alright, I'm gonna rewrite my answer based on this new information.

Comment: thank you, I think this is it. This statement is what I didn't know..where(lte('person')).by('minimumAge').by('age')..